# Oracle Java : Isn't NLS_TERRITORY enough to correctly format a number?

Tags: java, oracle, number-formatting

In my code I have an oracle connection on which I execute the following:

```
stmt.executeUpdate("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY='GREECE'");
```

Now, if I select a number from my table - let's say its value is `0,25` with

`rs.getString(1)` what I get is `'0.25'` not `'0,25'` as I was expecting...

What am I missing here?
Thanks.

**Edit 1.**

the sql below:

```
select 
    value
        from nls_session_parameters
        where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'
```

inside my session returns `',.'` 
which means that for the oracle comma is used as decimal separator.

It is also confirmed by the fact that when inserting into table - comma is expected - otherwise exception is thrown.

So the question remains... why getString behaves this way?

Comment: Whats the value for `NLS_LANG` in that case. Is should change. Check incase its changing. If not set it to `AMERICAN_GREECE.WE8ISO8859P1`

Comment: @XING NLS_LANG  is now  confirmed to be  `AMERICAN_GREECE` (it always was).  Take a look at my edit... I suspect that the problem is not at the database end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in your query is a `NUMBER` and it is being passed to Java as a `NUMBER` and stored in the ResultSet as a `NUMBER` then you are using `rs.getString()` to get the number as a String.

Oracle has nothing to do with the conversion of the data types, it is all internal to Java.

```
st = con.prepareStatement( "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY='GREECE'" );
st.executeUpdate();
st.close();

st = con.prepareStatement( "SELECT 1.23, TO_CHAR( 1.23 ) FROM DUAL" );
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();

System.out.println( md.getColumnTypeName( 1 ) + " " + md.getColumnTypeName( 2 ) );
while( rs.next() )
{
  System.out.println( rs.getString( 1 ) + " " + rs.getString( 2 ) );
}
```

Outputs:

```
NUMBER VARCHAR2
1.23 1,23
```

If you want Oracle to format the number then use `TO_CHAR` to format the number so that is passed to Java as a String and not a number.

Comment: You are absolutely right - it is an internal java conversion... now it is clear. And as you mentioned - `to_char` will do the trick ;-)  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This maybe help you;

```
    select value
    from nls_session_parameters
    where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';

VALUE                                  
----------------------------------------
.,
```

Check this value. If you want to with ',' (0,25) change parameter like ;

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';
```

Change ',' and '.' order.

Comment: I guess `NLS_TERRITORY` is introduced with some purpose. And it should serve it purpose if used correctly. Read more here  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_options074.htm#OLADM415

Comment: You are right. My advise is alternative wat for purpose.

Comment: Check https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG003 to see relations and dependencies of different NLS settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I did the above select - and the value returned is ',.'  as expected for Greek locale (decimal marker is comma). So the problem remains...  I am guessing that it has something to do with getString behaviour... By the way when I insert values - Db expects comma as a decimal delimiter.